# How to create a custom explicit wait function in selenium c# passing in WebElements instead of By

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver

Im trying to refactor my old code and one of the things on my checklist is to wrap my explicit wait into a function and just call the function.

Right now I'm using lambdas and not expected conditions because lamdas are the way to go in c# and  i dont want to be dependent on an obsolete class/unsupported nuget package.

to breakdown my current project, everytime i create a method i have defined an explicit wait like so:

```
public void someFunc()
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    wait.Until(driver => element.Displayed);
}
```

my hope is that instead of having to define my wait in each function i can just call a wait method and go from there.

The problem is im not sure how to do it effectively using WebElements as the parameter.

I have created as you can imagine something like this

```
public void waitForElement(IWebElement element)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    wait.Until(driver => element.Displayed);
}
```

but when i call this method in my tests or another function i get an exception, and thanks to another user i know why.

when i call

```
waitForElement(myWebElement);
```

webdriver fails because the element doesnt exist on the page just yet. its not reaching the code within the function because the element does not exist as the parameter.

I have tried everything from adding a driver as the parameter, from using the webdriverwait as the parameter and using a lambda as the argument, from changing the function to a bool and using the lambda)

Is there any good/clean way to do this in c#? am i missing something? please help

just note, i got it to work using the "By" as the parameter but i do not want to use by as it can lead to hard to maintain code.

Comment: You can try a single `implicit wait` when you set up your driver and see if that helps you. The implicit wait will delay all NoSuchElementsExecptions until the element EXISTS (exist != the right state, e.g. displayed) - you can then use your method to validate state as needed. The docs say you shouldn't use both wait types because it can cause inconsistent timing issues *ON FAILING* items. It is still dynamic wait (will continue when ready) and you can mitigate the timing impact by having the explicit time be a factor of the implicit.... Quite a long comment. Shout if you need to know more?

Comment: But you are right in your answer - A Webelement is a found element, you don't need to wait for it as you already have it.  Using a By is completely acceptable - you just have that as a property in a Page Object class file

Comment: writing By.Locator("locator") each time i need to use the wait is not ideal in my eyes, atleast in the page object class its just in one location. If i have to wait for multiple elements thats writing multiple Bys if the html changes the code can become unmanageable if im using multiple waits. 
I also feel like if i use the implicit wait along with the explicit it wouldnt really solve what i want because i would just be defining implicit waits in each function and if that was the case i would just leave the code as is with the explicit waits in the functions

Comment: You can extend selenium webdriver - potentially look to extend or override the core findElement with your own wait-induced implementation.  Or you can use methods for your elements instead of a lamda. With a method you'll only try to identify the element when called and that method can contain your sync function or the overrided findelement - it's difficult to suggest the right course without seeing your code + structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension method for the `WebDriverWait` class:

```
namespace OpenQA.Selenium
{
    public static class WebDriverWaitExtensions
    {
        public static void UntilElementIsDisplayed(this WebDriverWait wait, IWebElement element)
        {
            wait.Until(driver => element.Displayed);
        }
    }
}
```

Now any place you have a `WebDriverWait` object, you can call `wait.UntilElementIsDisplayed(element);`

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("..."));
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

wait.UntilElementIsDisplayed(element);
```

Just be sure to add `using OpenQA.Selenium;` to the top of your C# file.

This is a pattern I've used to replace nearly everything in the obsolete ExpectedConditions class. Extension methods and lambda expressions are the way to go.